# What is the equivalent tag for ScriptCollector?

Tags: jsf, migration, ibm-jsf

We want to migrate our project from IBM WebSphere 6.1 to Tomcat 6, but in our JSP-JSF UI pages we have extensively used below IBM JSF tags.

- ScriptCollector
- PanelRowCaregory
- PagerWeb
- OutPutSelections
- InputRowSelect
- InputHelperDatePicker
- InputHelperAssist
- ConvertMask

And to replace above tags, we are trying to find the equivalent tags from Sun JSF or any other open source libraries, but we didn't find any equivalent tags.

I wanted to know whether any body has already worked on this kind of migration project, if yes can you please share the equivalent tags?

or if you solved it differently even that info also will be useful.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

There's no standard JSF equivalent for the `<hx:scriptCollector>` (although the JSF 2.0 `<h:head>` comes close). The `<hx:scriptCollector>` is only required by those IBM-specific `<hx:xxx>` components. It's designed to collect all JavaScript files required by those `<hx:xxx>` components and then render the desired `<script>` tag(s) without potential duplicates when multiple components require the same JS files. It's not required by any standard JSF component.

In other words, just get rid of it without replacement.

---

As to other tags, just check the available standard components in tag documentation or Java EE tutorial. If none is available, just pick a component library like PrimeFaces or RichFaces. If you still can't figure out, ask an individual question for the particular tag.

Comment: Thanks a Lot BalusC. I really appreciate your help and guidance here. I will post separate questions for remaining tags